# Implemented Cubic Spline is not smooth

Tags: interpolation, spline

I want to implement cubic spline, so I found and implemented this [discription](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html) and this [method for solving tridiagonal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#Method). I'd like to draw without using any math libraries, so cubic spline is displayed by taking each piece of the spline, $Y_i(t)$, and connecting the points $(x_i + t*(x_{i+1} - x_i), Y_i(t))$ for $t$ between 0 and 1.

Now, when all $x_i$ are ascending and far enough from each other, spline looks good, like this:
[image]

But when more complicated cubic spline takes place (like in the description) by placing adjacent point vertically or in opposite direction, produced spline is not smooth:

[image]
[image]

What am I missing? Is there another type of spline, that doesn't have sharp corners (and picture in description was misplaced)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture on the Wolfram web page is highly misleading. It could not be produced by the algorithm they describe (without some significant modifications -- see below). The spline they describe (which you implemented) gives $y$ as a function of $x$. The algorithm relies on the fact that the input $x$ values are strictly increasing. So, in your second and third examples, I'm surprised that your code didn't crash.

The other common type of spline curve is a *parametric* spline. This has an equation of the form $\mathbf C(t) = \left( x(t), y(t) \right)$, where $x$ and $y$ are now spline functions that depend on a parameter $t$. With this approach, you can have curves that are vertical, or double back in the $x$-direction (like the one shown in the picture on the Wolfram site).

You can construct parametric cubic splines using the code you already wrote. Suppose you have data points $P_i = (x_i,y_i)$. First, you assign a parameter value $t_i$ to each data point $P_i$. There are many ways to do this, but the main point is that the $t_i$ values must be strictly increasing. Then use your code to compute a spline function $x(t)$ that fits the data $(t_i,x_i)$ and another spline function $y(t)$ that fits the data $(t_i,y_i)$. Then the curve $\mathbf C(t) = \left( x(t), y(t) \right)$ is what you want.

Comment: Got it working. What I did is found function for x axis the same way as for y, but independently from latter. Resulted (x(t), y(t)) is exactly what I was looking for.